# Two sucessive ImageShow showing the same image

Tags: c, opencv

I'm trying to visualize 2 successive images using OpenCV

Here are the 3 matrices I am computing:

```
projectionResult_img_debug = cvReshape( projectionResult_line, &row_header_temp, 0,    rect_list[9].height );
projectionResult_img_debug2 = cvReshape( AverageImg_line, &row_header_temp2, 0, rect_list[9].height );
projectionResult_img = cvReshape( projectionResult_line2, &row_header_temp3, 0, rect_list[9].height );


//debug:                                printMatrixValues(projectionResult_line, 1200, 1250);
printMatrixValues(AverageImg_line, 1200, 1250);
printMatrixValues(projectionResult_line2, 1200, 1250);

IplImage img_t;
IplImage* img_t2 = cvGetImage( projectionResult_img_debug,  &img_t );


IplImage img_t_2;
IplImage* img_t2_2 = cvGetImage( projectionResult_img,  &img_t );
```

My problem is that the 2 images that are displayed are the same, and are ALWAYS displaying the last matrix that I have computed (in this case it's the one on line 3).

Any idea of where the problem is?

Comment: I can't see  where you are displaying the images. There's no call to `cvShowImage()` on this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @karlphillip says, your code sample is incomplete. But it looks like the second argument in `IplImage* img_t2_2 = cvGetImage( projectionResult_img,  &img_t );` should probably be `img_t_2`.

Comment: Indeed that was the problem...  basically both Images header were indentical and pointing to the same data... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the most recent version of OpenCV, instead of displaying the images I would write them on disk using `cvSaveImage()`. If they are still equal, then there's a problem on your logic/code and it's not related to OpenCV displaying images.

Your code as it is, its incomplete and I can't help you any further. There's no call to `cvShowImage()` on this code.